# Access Query with Variable and Export to Excel

Tags: vba

When pressing a button I would like to execute a SQL statement which uses a variable.

For example:

```
SELECT a, b, 
FROM data 
WHERE a IS NOT NULL 
  AND b = '&<Variable>&';
```

Then the result of the query shall be exported into a worksheet of an Excel file.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you tried and how far have you gotten so far?

Comment: You could set a recordset as the SQL output which then you create an Excel book and use the .copyfromRecordset method to copy it in. I have code if you are interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have to create a SQL on the fly and save it for the DoCmd.OutputTo method to do the export for you. Something like.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub ExportQueryToExcel()
    Dim dbObj As DAO.Database, qdObj As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim filePath As String, sqlText As String, yourVariable As String
    Set dbObj = CurrentDb

    yourVariable = "Apple"

    sqlText = "SELECT a, b, c WHERE a Is Not Null And b = '" & yourVariable & "'"
    filePath = "C:\Users\P\Desktop\fileName.xlsx"

    On Error Resume Next
    With dbObj      
        .QueryDefs.Delete "tmpDataQry"
        Set qdfNew = .CreateQueryDef("tmpDataQry", sqlText)
        .Close
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "tmpDataQry", acFormatXLSX, filePath

    Set qdObj = Nothing
    Set dbObj = Nothing
End Sub
```